# phpseclib generated certificates integrity not guaranteed / corrupted

Tags: openssl, phpseclib

I use the following code to sign a CSR with my own CA:

```
<?php
require_once("vendor/autoload.php");

$privKey = new \phpseclib\Crypt\RSA();
$privKey->setHash('sha512');
$keypair = $privKey->createKey(4096);
$privKey->loadKey($keypair['privatekey']);
$pubKey = new \phpseclib\Crypt\RSA();
$pubKey->loadKey($keypair['publickey']);
$pubKey->setPublicKey();

$subject = new \phpseclib\File\X509();
$subject->setPrivateKey($privKey);
$subject->setPublicKey($pubKey);
$subject->setDNProp("id-at-organizationName", "??");
$subject->setDNProp("id-at-organizationalUnitName", "?");
$subject->setDNProp("id-at-commonName", "127.0.0.1");
$subject->setDNProp("id-at-localityName", "?");
$subject->setDNProp("id-at-stateOrProvinceName", "?");
$subject->setDNProp("id-at-countryName", "??");
$subject->setDNProp("emailAddress", "?");
$subject->loadCSR($subject->saveCSR($subject->signCSR('sha512WithRSAEncryption')));
$subject->setExtension('id-ce-basicConstraints', array('cA'=>FALSE));
$subject->setExtension('netscape-cert-type', ['SSLServer']);
$subject->setExtension('id-ce-keyUsage', ['digitalSignature', 'keyEncipherment'], TRUE);
$subject->setExtension('id-ce-extKeyUsage', ['id-kp-serverAuth', 'id-kp-OCSPSigning'], TRUE);
$strCSR = $subject->saveCSR($subject->signCSR('sha512WithRSAEncryption'));
file_put_contents("a.csr", $strCSR);

$cakey = new \phpseclib\Crypt\RSA();
$cakey->setPassword(file_get_contents("private/passphrase.txt"));
$cakey->loadKey(file_get_contents("private/cakey.pem"));
$ca = new \phpseclib\File\X509();
$ca->loadX509(file_get_contents("cacert.pem"));
$ca->setPrivateKey($cakey);
$x509 = new \phpseclib\File\X509();
$x509->makeCA();
@$x509->setEndDate(new \DateTime("2018-08-08 08:08:08", new \DateTimeZone(@date_default_timezone_get())));
$x509->setSerialNumber(999, 10);
$sign_result = $x509->sign($ca, $subject, $subject->currentCert['signatureAlgorithm']['algorithm']);
$cert = $x509->saveX509($sign_result);
file_put_contents("a.crt", $cert);
```

However, the signed certificate seems to have some problem like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/F4p5I.png

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

My environment info:

```
PHP 7.2.0
phpseclib 2.0
Windows 7
```

**EDIT:**
I used openssl to verify it, it looks like it's missing something after 
 the second "signature algorithm"...

```
Certificate:
    Data:
        ***********
    Signature Algorithm: sha512WithRSAEncryption
        ***************
        X509v3 extensions:
            ***********
    Signature Algorithm: sha512WithRSAEncryption
        **(something is missing here, there's nothing after this point)**
```

**EDIT:** my openssl.cnf

```
default_bits            = 4096
default_md              = sha512
dir         = "."
[ca]
default_ca      = CA_default
[CA_default]
serial          = $dir/serial.txt
database        = $dir/index.txt
new_certs_dir       = $dir/newcerts
certificate     = $dir/cacert.pem
private_key     = $dir/private/cakey.pem
default_days        = 3650
preserve        = no
email_in_dn     = no
nameopt         = default_ca
certopt         = default_ca
policy          = policy_match
default_crl_days = 365
[policy_match]
countryName     = optional
stateOrProvinceName = optional
organizationName    = optional
organizationalUnitName  = optional
commonName      = supplied
emailAddress        = supplied
[req]
string_mask     = nombstr
distinguished_name  = req_distinguished_name
req_extensions      = v3_req
[req_distinguished_name]
............
[v3_ca]
basicConstraints    = CA:TRUE
subjectKeyIdentifier    = hash
authorityKeyIdentifier  = keyid:always,issuer:always
keyUsage                = critical, cRLSign, digitalSignature, keyCertSign
[v3_req]
........
```

Comment: It worked fine for me when I used a valid private key and valid CA cert. Since you didn't post private/cakey.pem or cacert.pem I guess my questions would be...  is the private key an RSA private key? ECDSA / DSA keys are not currently supported by phpseclib. And does the private key correspond to the cert? If you could generate a test CA cert with a test private key and if you could post those I could better reproduce the problem, but until then, I'm only grasping at straws.

Comment: It's also possible that your CA cert isn't installed as a CA cert in your system..

Comment: my CA cert is generated using `openssl req -new -x509 -extensions v3_ca -keyout ca.key 
-out ca.crt -config ./openssl.cnf
`; I did try to install my CA in the browser, but still in vain.

Comment: What type of key is ca.key? ECDSA? DSA? RSA? What parameters are in ca.crt? I'd just assume have a sample CA cert and private key that reproduce the problem because, without that, the best I'm going to be able to do is guess. With it I could install it locally and exactly reproduce the problem..

Comment: my ca.key is RSA.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that your CA cert has not been installed. This is not a phpseclib problem nor is it even a programming problem. Indeed, this question would be better placed on superuser.com.

That said, I was able to reproduce your problem.

Here's what I got on I clicked on the cert that that generated.

[image]

The CA cert wasn't installed:

[image]

I performed the following steps:

1. Click on "Install Certificate..." for the CA cert
2. Click "Next"
3. Select "Place all certificates in the following store"
4. Click "Browse..."
5. Select "Trusted Root Certification Authorities"
6. Click "OK"
7. Click "Next"
8. Click "Finish"
9. Click "Yes"
10. Click "OK"

Here's what I got after that:

[image]